# How to animate a SVG polygon to fill?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, css-animations

I have a SVG letter (A) that consists of two polygon and a rectangle. I want to animate them in a way that **the first polygon grows to visible and then the second one**. After that, the rectangle will grow to be visible. Before the start of the animation, the SVG will not be visible.

I have tried keyframe strokes but as they are not path based but points of polygon, it didn't work.

```html
<svg height="600" width="800">
  <polygon  points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51"/>
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="5s" fill="freeze"  />
  
   <polygon  points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55"/>
   <rect x="120" y="320"  stroke-miterlimit="10" width="270" height="120"/>
 </svg>
```

Here is a pen if you want to work on it : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vMxXaP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still draw the (A) letter by using polygons with stroke instead of fill. The following example uses two keyframe animations on stroke-dasharray to draw the A letter in two steps :

1. First step for the top left and top right line (first polygon element in the svg)
2. Second step for the horizontal line closing the A (second polygon in the svg element)

```css
.letter {
  width:200px;height:auto;
  stroke-width:2.5;
  stroke:#000;
  fill:none;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 24;
}
.animateFirst { animation: 0.5s animateFirst ease-in forwards; }
.animateSecond { animation: 0.2s 0.45s animateSecond ease-out forwards; }

@keyframes animateFirst {
  to { stroke-dasharray: 24 24; }
}
@keyframes animateSecond {
  to { stroke-dasharray: 6 24; }
}
```

```html
<svg class="letter" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
  <polygon class="animateFirst" points="1,11.5 6,0 11,11.5" />
  <polygon class="animateSecond" points="3,6.5 9,6.5" />  
</svg>
```

Comment: Feels the hand of the master It’s a pity that you have rarely responded lately

Comment: @Alexandr_TT well thats a very nice comment, thank you :)

Comment: I studied your old works. I really liked them, translated a lot into Russian. SO Of course, I always pointed to the source.

Comment: works just perfectly as I asked for! Thank you so much man! much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Bonus version. Here i turned your paths into mask and added background animation.

[image]

```html
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 600 800">
   <style>  
    svg {
      height:160px;
      background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Pr8tfnT.png);
      background-position: 0px 111px;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-size: 100%;
      animation: water 10s forwards;
    }

    @keyframes water {
      100% {
        background-position: 2000px 0px;
      }
    }
   </style>   
   <mask id="mask" fill="black">
    <rect fill="white" width="600" height="800"/>
    <polygon id="right" points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55"/>
    <polygon id="left"  points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51"/>
    <rect id="rect1" x="120" y="320"  stroke-miterlimit="10" width="270" height="120"/> 
   </mask>

   <rect fill="white" width="600" height="800" mask="url(#mask)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: this is hot....

Answer (score 4):

### SVG solution

Rotation and appearance animation

```css
.container {
 width:35%;
 height:35%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">

<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 600 800">
  <g fill="black" fill-opacity="0" >
    <polygon
      id="left" transform="rotate(72 306 200)"  points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51"> 
         <animateTransform
   attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   values="72 306 200;0 306 200"
   begin="svg1.click"
   dur="0.5s"
   fill="freeze" />  
  <animate
    id="an_op1"
    attributeName="fill-opacity"
    from="0"
    to="1"
    begin="svg1.click"
    dur="0.5s"
    fill="freeze" /> 
 </polygon>  
    <polygon id="right"  transform="rotate(-69 457.5 200)" 
        points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55">
  <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   values="-69 457.5 200;0 457.5 200" 
   begin="an_op1.end"
   dur="0.5s"
   fill="freeze" />  
  <animate
     id="an_op2"
  attributeName="fill-opacity"
  from="0"
  to="1"
  begin="an_op1.end"
  dur="0.5s"
  fill="freeze" />
 </polygon>   
        <rect id="rect1"  x="800" y="320"    width="270" height="120"> 
          <animate
     attributeName="x"
     from="800"
     to="120"
     begin="an_op2.end"
     dur="0.5s"
     fill="freeze" /> 
      <animate
     id="an_op3"
     attributeName="fill-opacity"
     from="0"
     to="1"
     begin="an_op2.end"
     dur="0.5s"
     fill="freeze" />
     </rect>     
   </g>  
      <text x="0" y="80" font-size="50" fill="purple">Click me</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

**Second solution**

All animation elements are invisible at the beginning. `fill-opacity="0"`

Item appearance Animation:

```
<animate
      id="an_left"
      attributeName="fill-opacity"
      begin="1s"
      from="0"
      to="1"
      dur="0.3s"
      fill="freeze"/>
```

Below is the full code:

```css
.container {
width:35%;
height:35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 600 800">
  
    <polygon id="right" fill="#008080" fill-opacity="0" 
    points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55">
    <animate
      id="an_right"
   attributeName="fill-opacity"
   begin="an_left.end"
   from="0"
   to="1"
   dur="0.3s"
   fill="freeze"/>
 </polygon>   

 <polygon  id="left" fill="#008080" fill-opacity="0" points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51">
   <animate
   id="an_left"
   attributeName="fill-opacity"
   begin="0.2s"
   from="0"
   to="1"
   dur="0.3s"
   fill="freeze"/>
  </polygon> 

    <rect x="120" y="320" fill="#008080" fill-opacity="0" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="270" height="120"> 
     <animate
  id="an_rect"
  attributeName="fill-opacity"
  from="0"
  to="1"
  begin="an_right.end"
  dur="0.3s"
  fill="freeze"/>
 </rect> 
</svg>
</div>
```

The sequence of animations is achieved by a chain of conditions in the attribute - `begin="an_left.end"`

Such a record means that the animation of the right rectangle will begin only after the end of the animation of the left polygon.

### CSS solution

```css
.container {
width:35%;
height:35%;
}
#left,#right,  #rect1 {
fill-opacity:0;
fill:#008080;

}
#left {
animation:anLeft  0.3s ease forwards;
animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

@keyframes anLeft {
  100% {
    fill-opacity:1;
 
  }
} 
#right {
animation:anRight  0.3s ease forwards;
animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@keyframes anRight {
  100% {
    fill-opacity:1;
  }
}  

#rect1 {
animation:anRect  0.3s ease forwards;
animation-delay:0.7s;
}

@keyframes anRect {
  100% {
    fill-opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 600 800">
  
    <polygon id="right"  
    points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55"/>
 <polygon  id="left"  points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51"/>
    <rect id="rect1" x="120" y="320"  stroke-miterlimit="10" width="270" height="120"/> 
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Animating the `fill-opacity` is the best choice.

Comment: Hey man! you answer was almost perfect for me but web-tiki posted the perfect one. But thanks a lot for the answer brother!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this using CSS keyframes, is this what you're looking for?

```css
    @keyframes fade {
      from {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    
    #right {
      animation-delay: 1s;
    }
    
    #center {
      animation-delay: 2s;
    }
    
    .shape {
      opacity: 0;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 1s;
    }
```

```html
<svg id="abcdef" height="600" width="800">
      <polygon class="shape" points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51"/>
      <polygon id="right" class="shape" points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55"/>
      <rect id="center" class="shape"  x="120" y="320" filter="#008080" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="270" height="120"/>
    </svg>
```

If you want to tweak the duration of the animation you have to look at changing the values of `animation-delay` and `animation-duration`.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example with pure javascript and changing opacity by delta time

```js
let left = document.querySelector('#left')
let right = document.querySelector('#right')
let rect1 = document.querySelector('#rect1')
let time = 3000; // animation time
let delay = 1000; // animation delay

// dt - time from animation start
function animate(dt) { 
 let v = dt - delay;  
 opacity(left, v/time*3);     
 opacity(right, v/time*3 - 1);
 opacity(rect1, v/time*3 - 2);
 dt < time + delay + 50 && requestAnimationFrame(animate)
} 

function opacity(el, v) {
 v = Math.min(1, Math.max(v, 0)); // clamp to 0-1
 el.setAttribute('opacity', v)
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="175" viewBox="0 0 600 800">
  <g fill="#008080">
    <polygon id="right" opacity="0" points="411 537,528 537,364 118,354 91,348 72,341 53,327 53,223 55"/>
    <polygon id="left" opacity="0" points="34 537,150 536,289 130,314 53,196 51"/>
    <rect id="rect1" opacity="0" x="120" y="320"  stroke-miterlimit="10" width="270" height="120"/> 
   </g> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use keyframes, in there there a lot of things to do besides just the opacity. You can animate drawing the outlines with `stroke-dashoffset` and `stroke-dasharray`. There are also ways to let them fade in from let and right with `translateX` or `translateY`. Also rotation animations. 
take a look at the css in the pen i made: https://codepen.io/YilmazTut/pen/JzaQEy .

there also is a series on svg's from css tricks: https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/
i used that to create the logo in my pen. from about tutorial 16 he explains how animations and later on also pathdrawing works. I hope you can find your way there!

Comment: i can also try to create something for your svg aswell, but i will need you to be a bit more specific in how exactly it needs to be animated.